# Pyinstaller FileNotFoundError: 'C:\\Users\\axela\\PycharmProjects\\RT_HMap\\dist\\main\\cmlib\\version.txt'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Good evening
Im new to python and I wanted to make an executable with pyinstaller but Im gettin the following error.
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\alexa\PycharmProjects\RT_HMap\dist\main\cmlib\version.txt'
Does anybody know what it means and how I can solve it ?

Edit: the complete error would be
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8ud2.png)

Comment: It means the file `version.txt` does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'C:\Users\alexa\PycharmProjects\RT_HMap\dist\main\cmlib\version.txt'

This just means that the file 'version.txt' doesn't exist

One of the main goals of a PyInstaller-created executable is for users to not need anything installed on their machine. one of the packages requires a version.txt file. You can add this file to the build using the --add-data option. Here’s an [example](https://realpython.com/pyinstaller-python/#testing-your-new-executable)

Comment: Yes I know but I don't understand why it does not exist

Comment: one of the main goals of a PyInstaller-created executable is for users to not need anything installed on their machine.
The importlib_resources package requires a version.txt file. You can add this file to the build using the --add-data option.  [Here’s an example](https://realpython.com/pyinstaller-python/#testing-your-new-executable)

Comment: Ah ok I tried that with the following command but it did not work :/
pyinstaller main.py \ --add-data venv/Lib/site-packages/pgcolorbar/version.txt:pgcolorbar



I get the following error
pyinstaller: error: argument --add-data: invalid add_data_or_binary value: 
'venv/Lib/site-packages/pgcolorbar/version.txt:pgcolorbar'

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about this path, just try to replace the '' by '/' in your path. It should work then :)

Comment: Like this /venv/Lib/site-packages/pgcolorbar/version.txt:pgcolorbar ?

Comment: like this : 
C:/Users/alexa/PycharmProjects/RT_HMap/dist/maincmlib/version.txt
or :
C:\\Users\\alexa\\PycharmProjects\\RT_HMap\\dist\\main\\cmlib\\version.txt

If this doesn't work, your path is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I used the following command that worked. The errors mostly came from me not realising that I have to use ; instead of : on Windows.

pyinstaller main.py \ --add-data venv\Lib\site-packages\pgcolorbar\version.txt **;** dist\main\cmlib.

However I'm still getting the following weird error:

File "c:\users\alexa\pycharmprojects\pythonproject2\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1407, in run_script
with open(pathname, 'rb') as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\'